# How to forward a message in Telegram API

Tags: api, telegram

There are 2 methods in Telegram API that forward message:

- messages.forwardMessage
- messages.forwardMessages

I want to use `forwardMessage` method to forward a message from a `channel`, `group` or `user` to another one. Definition of this method is:

```
messages.forwardMessage#33963bf9 peer:InputPeer id:int random_id:long = Updates;
```

As you see this method has 3 input parameters:

- `peer` that represents the `channel`, `group` or `user` that we forward message to. (Destination)
- `id` that is `message_id`.
- `random_id` that has internal use.

As we know the `message_id` is a unique number in a chat. so a `message_id` in a `group` has refers to a message that differs with the same `message_id` in other group.

So the main question is that how we determine the source `peer` of forwarding? Because the source `peer` is not determined by `message_id`.

P.S: My question is about methods in Telegram API, not Telegram Bot API.

Comment: The message is being forwarded by you, from your session, hence are you not the source?

Comment: Where do you need the source? I think you are a little bit confused about the forward function. Maybe you can clarify your question a little bit. The function takes 3 parameters: the message_id, the destination group, and a random number. The message_id is unique for every message sent to telegram.

Comment: @apadana, At first I have thought like you. I was thinking that the `message_id` is unique inside Telegram so it must be a big number. but after the test I considered that `message_id` is unique only inside the chat. so it is a small int like 2, 5, ... .

Comment: @Charles, how can we get the `message_id` that be unique in our session? By `getHistory` method I get messages in a particular `peer` and then the `message_id` is unique only in that `peer` not in our session.

Comment: @AmirZojaji The number is unique to your bot. When your bot receives messages, each message has a unique message_id. If the numbers are 1,2,3,4, 5 it means your bot is new and those are the first few messages your bot received. Once your bot gets older, the numbers would increase.  So again each message your bot received will have its own number which is unique for the purpose of forwarding to another group. Hope this explains.

Comment: @apadana, I am not speaking about Telegram Bot API. All methods that I speaking about is in Telegram API.

Comment: @AmirZojaji It's the same concept for telegram API. Each authenticated user will get a unique message id. So personX may get message5, and personY may also get message5. Each of them when forward the message will forward their own message5.

Comment: @apadana, , how can we get the `message_id` that be unique in for a particular? By `getHistory` method I get messages in a particular `peer` and then the `message_id` is unique only in that peer not in our session.

Comment: @AmirZojaji For getHistory, Input peer is "Target user or group". It's the chat id of the group or the user. Each group (or user chat) have their own id. If you need a unique number across your system/session, you need to save the combination of (chat_id, message_id).

Comment: @apadana, You are are reaching to my problem gradually. in `getHistory` method we het the messages of a `chat` (`group` or `channel` or `user`). but when we give a `channel_id` to it, we get the messages of that channel with `message_id`s unique only in that channel. so when we want to forward that message, we can only get 'message_id` to `forwardMessage` method, not chat_id. ok?

Comment: @AmirZojaji you must be forwarding your message as a user, right? Which user is that? Have you done authorization to the API?

Comment: @apadana, When I use the `user_id` of the current user as the parameter of `getHistory`, We receive no messages at output. This is clearly because I don't have a chat with myself!

Comment: @apadana, I wish your point was true, but unfortunately not. I recommend you to test it.

Comment: @AmirZojaji can you describe a simple test scenario which shows your point?

Comment: As I mentioned before I get messages by `getHistory` method and all messages of a particular channel. There is only 7 messages in this channel that their `message_id`s are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7. There are many other channels related to this user and several of them are joined before this channel.

Comment: @AmirZojaji I updated my answer. You are right. Today I hit this issue and noticed message_id is not unique. I think previously I didn't have enough chats in my test env to face the issue. Today I noticed forwardMessage forwards the wrong message. But forwardMessages works fine and my answer below is based on that.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to an issue with ForwardMessageRequest which doesn't specify the source chat. Obviously message_id is not unique and through my tests I noticed wrong messages will be forwarded by just specifying the message_id. And I noticed message_id is not unique.

But the issue doesn't exist with ForwardMessagesRequest. Following is an example how to use the ForwardMessagesRequest version.

**Forwarding Example:**

Here is the code I used for testing (I am using Telethon for python, but it won't matter since it's directly calling telegram API):

```
source_chat = InputPeerChannel(source_chat_id, source_access_hash)
total_count, messages, senders = client.get_message_history(
                    source_chat, limit=10)

for msg in reversed(messages):
    print ("msg:", msg.id, msg)

msg = messages[0]    
print ("msg id:", msg.id)

dest_chat = InputPeerChat(dest_chat_id)    

result = client.invoke(ForwardMessagesRequest(from_peer=source_chat, id=[msg.id], random_id=[generate_random_long()], to_peer=dest_chat))
```