# How to obtain chatid of a private channel by given joinlink using Telegram API?

Tags: api, telegram, channel

I have a join link like this: https://t.me/joinchat/AAAAAEI95pT9clShebEcMg

I want to know the functions that leads me to obtain the chatid of that channel.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use telegram API function `messages.checkChatInvite`

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.messages.check_chat_invite import CheckChatInviteRequest


client = TelegramClient('session_id', '+phonenumber', api_id=1234, api_hash='0cxxxxxxx')
client.connect()

channel_hash = "AAAAAxxxxxxxx"
result = client.invoke(CheckChatInviteRequest(channel_hash))
print (result)
```

and the result would be something like this:

```
(chatInviteAlready (ID: 0x5abcdefg) = (chat=(channel (ID: 0x5abcdefg) = (creator=None, kicked=None, left=None, editor=True, moderator=None, broadcast=True, verified=None, megagroup=None, restricted=None, democracy=None, signatures=None, min=None, id=123456789, access_hash=615xxxxxxxxx, title=testChannel, username=None, photo=(chatPhotoEmpty (ID: 0x37xxxxxxx) = ()), date=2017-06-14 14:34:50, version=0, restriction_reason=None))))
```

Here the id in the response is the channel id you are looking for. 
The above example is using Telethon and python, but you may use any language and client to connect to telegram API.

Comment: Thanks for this useful help, but how can i have the channel hash first?

Comment: @Burzum the channel hash is the one at the end of the url you sent. In your example it is AAAAAEI95pT9clShebEcMg

Comment: @Burzum If you found my answer helpful please mark it as accepted. Let me find an example for you how to send a message to a channel, but wait, members can't send message to channel. They need to be admin. Is this a group or channel you are trying to message to?

Comment: @Burzum see the result of checkChatInvite in my answer's result, it already has the access_hash: id=123456789, access_hash=615xxxxxxxxx.

Comment: @Burzum for groups you don't need the access_hash. only for super groups you need the access hash. so you are find just to send message with chat_id.

Comment: @Burzum you need to convert the chat_id to chat by using InputPeerChat. Like this chat = InputPeerChat(chat_id) and then call send_message(chat, 'Test')

Comment: @Burzum maybe using the access_hash is a good indication to distinguish btw the two. If the result doesn't have access_hash it's a group. Forward message using telethon would be like this: result = client.invoke(ForwardMessageRequest(chat, message.id, generate_random_long())).check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43523018/how-to-forward-a-message-in-telegram-api?noredirect=1#comment74138733_43523018

Comment: @Burzum If you still have question for forwardmessage please post a question and I will try to answer later today. If you posted a question please ping me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146991/discussion-between-burzum-and-apadana).